# thread is throwing HRESULT 800ac472 error

Tags: .net, excel, vba

I am creting a thread and reading the dataset and writing the records into excel.
But the thread is not reading complete records and breaks in the middle after reading 25 records.

```
        If dsCostUsage.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 150 Then
            Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf FillDataRows1)
            t.Start(worksheet)
        End If


Private Sub FillDataRows1(ByVal ws As Worksheet)

    Dim startuprow As Integer = 7
    Dim colpointer As Integer = 0
    Dim rowpointer As Integer = 0
    Dim str As String
        While rowpointer <= dsCostUsage.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            While colpointer <= dsCostUsage.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                str = dsCostUsage.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer)(colpointer).ToString()
                DirectCast(ws.Cells(startuprow, colpointer + 1), Range).Value2 = item
                colpointer += 1
            End While
            colpointer = 0
            rowpointer += 1
            startuprow += 1
        End While

    End sub
```

Dont know the exact reason whhy it breaks in the middle.
Is there anyway that we need to increase the time or anhything else is there?

I think before worker thread completes writing, the main thread completes and interrupt the worker thread to not to continue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling t.Join()

That should make the main thread wait until the other(s) finish.