# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException when I use Microsoft.interop.Excel.dll

Tags: c#, excel

I use `Microsoft.interop.Excel.dll` to convert Excel to .pdf. The core code:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using ExcelApplicationClass =        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass;

public static bool ExcelToPdf(string sourcePath, string targetPath, out string exmsg)
    {

        exmsg = string.Empty;
        bool result = false;
        object missing = Type.Missing;

        ExcelApplicationClass applicationClass = null;
        
        Workbook workBook = null;
        try
        {
            applicationClass = new ExcelApplicationClass();               
            applicationClass.Visible = false;
           /* applicationClas*/
            workBook = applicationClass.Workbooks.Open(sourcePath);
          
           
            if (workBook != null)
            {

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workBook.ActiveSheet as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;
                //*** if I annotation the block in this if. the code no error occured.
                if (worksheet != null)
                {
                    worksheet.PageSetup.Zoom = false;
                    worksheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;                    

                }
                
                workBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, targetPath, XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityMinimum, false, true);
              
            }
            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exmsg = ex.Message;
            result = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (workBook != null)
            {
                workBook.Close(true,missing, missing);
                workBook = null;
            }
            if (applicationClass != null)
            {
                applicationClass.Quit();
                applicationClass = null;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

If I don't set `worksheet.PageSetup's` property like `zoom` etc. the program  runs well but if I set the property `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` will occur nine times out of ten. Sometime there is no error.

#### The error info

[image]

#### The environment information

- Microsoft Excel 2013
- Windows 10
- Every time it has killed the `Microsoft Excel` progress.

Comment: Google "excel error 50290".  Lots of hits, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140869/createobject-excel-application-throws-an-error-on-left-click-during-a-loop).

Comment: Related: [Thread is throwing 800AC472 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224721/thread-is-throwing-hresult-800ac472-error)

Comment: Don't cut the inner exception away. Most of the time it is closer to the root problem.